# как совместить функцию и классификатор в make_pipeline sklearn?

Tags: python, регрессия, pipelines, word2vec

у меня есть функция pipe_vec, которая принимает на вход текст и возвращает вектор word2vec, еще у меня есть обученная на этих векторах линейная регрессия.
Я пытаюсь их совместить в make_pipeline, но не получается

```
make_pipeline(pipe_vec, clf)
```

Но вылезает ошибка:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be
the string 'passthrough' '<function pipe_vec at 0x000001DD9CE24670>' (type <class 'function'>) doesn't
```

Я понимаю, почему она вылезает, но мне нужно их совместить так, чтобы я потом смог послать соединенную функцию в Eli5

```
from eli5.lime import TextExplainer
te = TextExplainer(random_state=42)
te.fit(text, pipe.predict_proba)
```

Есть ли способ совместить word2vec и логистическую регрессию, чтобы потом получившийся pipeline можно было использовать в eli5?